# How to create effect of smoothscroll loading between 2 separate pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I have a standard implementation of bootstrap's smoothscroll.js on my page, which works fine moving between different anchors.

However, the page is quite long to load, and I've been advised best practice to split this into 2 pages. Any ideas how I could modify the JS to still achieve the same appearance of smooth scroll between pages?

I'm stumped at how I might try to do this; fairly new to coding!

Thanks

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the smooth scrolling it's calculated based the content of the page, so if you load the sencond part via ajax and append it, what can be fail?

Answer (score 0):

If it was split in 2 different HTML, use `<script src="yourscript.js"></script>` on both pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the scrollto value in the url as a hash, and in your doc.ready function for both pages you can check the url for a scrollto value. If found, execute a smoothscroll to that location.

Here's a simple 'hash fetching' function I use:

```
// GET URL HASH VALUES ( USE:  getUrlVars() - RETURNS ARRAY... getUrlVars()["hashName"] - RETURNS STRING  ... [ url.html?something=1&otherThing=ABC ] )
function getUrlVars(){var a={};return window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,function(b,c,d){a[c]=d}),a}
```

And in your doc.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var pageGoto = getUrlVars()["scrollTo"];

  if (pageGoto){
    smoothScroller(pageGoto);
  }
});
```

And your links to target a location on a different page would be something like this:

```
<a href="mypage.html?scrollTo=some-content">My Link</a>
```

---

If you're looking to use ajax to append additional information on the page you can set an attribute on the page to indicate which links need to append new content prior to executing your scroll. Either in bulk (there's just 1 other page with all the secondary content) or *al e carte* (loading only the additional content relevant to that link).

html:

```
<a href="#my-content' data-fetch="my-content.html">Goto My Content</a>
```

js:

```
$('a').filter('[data-fetch]').click(function(e){
  var clicked = $(e.target).closest('a')
  ,   fetch = clicked.attr('data-fetch')
  ;

  $.ajax({
    url: fetch,
    success: function(data){

      $('body').append(data);
      smoothScroller(clicked.attr('href'));

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I was confused on this part of his post at first, too. I do not think he actually intends to redirect to the other page, I think he means to load it in and append it to his current page.

Answer (score 0):

Please show us your code. We cannot tell you for sure what is wrong if we cannot see the issue, ourselves.

My best guess would be that you are loading the content into an element that you have selected with jQuery on `$(document).ready`. The selector's content may not have updated after loading (use-case dependent), meaning that the JavaScript would only see the content that was originally in the selected element. As such, it would only scroll the length of the selected element's original height.